# Buñuel and Dalí

Tags: cinema-history

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Bu%C3%B1uel#L.27Age_d.27Or_.281930.29), Buñuel and Dalí had a falling out around the time the former was filming [L'Age d'Or](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021577/).  Is it known whether they ever restored their friendship?

Comment: According to the link you posted Buñuel, shoot Dalí  a few years later, so: No, I don't think they ever restored their friendship...

Comment: I could be completely off-base here... but I'm not really sure that this is about movies. Two guys being friends, even if they're both filmmakers, isn't really about films or TV.

Comment: the more i think about it, the more i agree, @Catija

Comment: Why did you delete this? It seemed like a reasonable question. Maybe a little bit more elaboration about Dali's influence on Bunuel's creative style (or the mutual influence between both) might have worked to make it a bit more fitting. But on the base I think the question could have worked.